# UIPickerview iOS6 vs iOS7 viewForRow

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uipickerview

i'm developing a view with three textfields that use uipickerview. The pickerview is the same but the content is dynamic depending on the textfield that a user is editing.

If i run the application on a device with iOS7 there are not problems but if i run it on a device with iOS6 when i scroll the picker view i see the old values and no correct values are showed for any row. What is the matter?

This is the source code

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:   (NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UIView *pickerCustomView = (id)view;
//pickerCustomView = [[UIView alloc] init];
UILabel *pickerViewLabel;
UIImageView *pickerImageView;
NSString *testo;
UIImage *immagine;


if (mieiCalc.isEditing) {

    NSString *imgRuolo =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
     [[mieiArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"RUOLO"],
     @".png"];
    testo = [[mieiArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"CALCIATORE"];

    testo =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",
     [[mieiArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"CALCIATORE"],
     @" (",
     [[mieiArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"COSTO"],
     @")"
     ];


    immagine = [variabiliGlobali imageResize:imgRuolo larghezza:30];
}
else if (squadreCalc.isEditing) {
    testo = [tutteSquadreArray  objectAtIndex:row];
    immagine = [variabiliGlobali imageResize:[variabiliGlobali getImgSquadra:testo] larghezza:30];
}
else {
    testo =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",
     [[altriArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"CALCIATORE"],
     @" (",
     [[altriArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"COSTO"],
     @")"
     ];
    immagine = [variabiliGlobali imageResize:[variabiliGlobali getImgSquadra:[[altriArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"SQUADRA"]] larghezza:30];

}

if (!pickerCustomView) {
    pickerCustomView= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

    if (!SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        pickerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 10, 30, 30)];
        pickerViewLabel= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 10, 270, 30)];
    }
    else {
        pickerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 30, 30)];
        pickerViewLabel= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 10, 270, 30)];

    }
    pickerViewLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    // the values for x and y are specific for my example
    [pickerCustomView addSubview:pickerImageView];
    [pickerCustomView addSubview:pickerViewLabel];
}

pickerImageView.image = immagine;
pickerViewLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
pickerViewLabel.text = testo; // where therapyTypes[row] is a specific example from my code
//pickerViewLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ChalkboardSE-Regular" size:20];

[pickerViewLabel setFont:MYFONT(20)];

return pickerCustomView;
}
```

Comment: You aren't providing the details needed to help you. You seem to determine which view to return based on the values `mieiCalc.isEditing` and `squadreCalc.isEditing`. But you don't tell us what those are or how they are set. You don't tell us how the picker view is setup or when it's reloaded based on the which text field is selected. And before posting this question you should have spent a lot of time using the debugger to track down the issue. What have you done so far to determine the issue?

Comment: BTW - iOS 8 will be out soon (most likely in September). At this point in time you should be writing your app to support iOS 7 and iOS 8. There is virtually no reason to be writing an app at this point that supports iOS 6.

Answer (score -1):

i have solved in this way. I have added this source code

```
if (pickerImageView == nil) {
    pickerImageView = view.subviews[0];

}

if (pickerViewLabel == nil) {

    pickerViewLabel = view.subviews[1];
}
```

The view of pickerview is reused and so the label and UIImageLabel was not refreshed.